# Scroll Box using Main scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have scroll box in my website, i want to make it move using main scroll bar..

Here's my preview:
[image]

Here's my code html:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
                <section>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 service-one">
                      <h1 class="header-caption">Service One</h1>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi perspiciatis sequi, autem, ea ratione praesentium et quis fugit.</p>
                      <ul>
                        <li>List One</li>
                        <li>List Two</li>
                        <li>List Three</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="col-md-6 service-one-img">
                      <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/service-img.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 service-one">
                      <h1 class="header-caption">Service One</h1>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi perspiciatis sequi, autem, ea ratione praesentium et quis fugit.</p>
                      <ul>
                        <li>List One</li>
                        <li>List Two</li>
                        <li>List Three</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="col-md-6 service-one-img">
                      <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/service-img.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
    
</div>
```

Here's my js:

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          $(document).scroll(function(){
              $('#wrapper').stop().animate({
                  scrollTop : $(this).scrollTop()
              });            
          });
      });
    </script>
```

and my css:

```
#wrapper {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 90%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Do you guys know how to make it works? So my scroll box can move using main scroll bar..

I have tried to code like that, and still my scroll box move using their own scroll bar, not using main scroll bar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just set the height of the wrapper to a larger one so that the content doesn't need to have their own scroll bar. The `overflow-y:auto` sets it into `scroll` because the height of the content is larger than the wrapper. If you want the height to just occupy the least amount of space you can use `height:fit-content`. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content). You may want to remove the script first before trying this.

Edit: I read your comment. As far as I know you cannot edit the function of the main scroll bar so it is not possible for your target. What you can do though could be a lot more tedious to do. So you can have the wrapper set to `position: absolute` and `z-index:0`. Then you will have your 2 main content (above and below scrolling box) at `z-index:1` and have it with `margin:40vh 0`. This doesn't work if you scroll with the main scroll bar, just when you scroll using mouse, mousepad, or  mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `height` on your `wrapper` if you want to use your main scrollbar. What is your intention for giving it a height?

Comment: I did remove it, and content inside wrapper is not showing.. i set wrapper for scrolling box and inside wrapper also have content there.. My target is, when main scroll bar reach scroll box, the scroll box will move and show all content inside scroll box using main scroll bar, and when scroll box reach end of their content, main scroll bar will scroll the rest of page content